# Metro App Glyph Icon Custom Size

Tags: .net, button, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, appbar

How do I override the `AppBarButtonStyle` `Width/Height` for a custom `Button` that I define?

Is it possible to represent a **Segoe UI Font Symbol** in a control other than `Button`? If so, how?

Comment: It would be easiest in Blend and of course it is possible. What are you trying to achieve though?

Comment: I would like to use a symbol from the Segoe UI Font, without having to represent it as an AppBarButton, so that I set a custom style/size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a `TextBlock` and set its `FontFamily` to *Segoe UI Symbol* and the text to the code of the glyph you you want shown that you can find in the character map app, e.g. `Text="&#xE101;"`. Then change any other properties of your `TextBlock` that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this even in code like this 
 `textblock1.Text = ((char)0xE101).ToString();` and assign font family as Segoe UI Symbol